# How to make Windows 7 to auto logon after boot from LAN only?

Tags: windows-7, wake-on-lan, automatic-logon

I would like to stop waiting my PC at work to boot every morning (and install updates sometimes). The idea is to wake up the PC remotely and logon with my domain user and password.
I managed with both parts, but now Windows is doing automatic logon with my credential every time.

I would like to keep the logon screen for any other user, who will power up the PC locally and enable the automatic logon only after wake on LAN.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible if there are multiple users.  If it is possible you would have to pick one to be the default which might not be workable.

Comment: That's what I've tried. I can pick a default, but then it is always default... I thought one can distinguish between normal boot and boot after wake on lan.

Answer (score 1):

This feature may not be possible as Windows cannot differentiate who powered on the machine (be it WoL or a physical button push!)

Answer (score 0):

[LogonExpert](http://www.logonexpert.com) with scheduled autologon + pc wake-up + lock desktop features enabled.

Answer (score -1):

You could switch on your PC using the command CONTROL USERPASSWORD2. Set a user with restricted rigthts then you can change the user. The  problem is that any time you have to change user, you need to switch the computer on by button as well.